# How can I make a different innerText for every DIV created in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I have one small problem in JS. I need to create around seven DIVs with a for function, but each div's content (here is innerText) must be different. Is there any way to do it with a function, without modifying each and every div by hand? If I put it inside the for function, the innerText will be the same.
Below is my code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      const innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
      innerDiv.id = "innerDivID";
      innerDiv.classList.add("innerDivClass");
      innerDiv.innerText = 1;
      outsideCaroussel.appendChild(innerDiv);
}
```

Note: outsideCaroussel is another div inside the Wrapper.

Comment: Does the content matter? If you just need something different you could use your loop counter variable, eg `innerText = i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you should put `i` to the div as a text:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      const innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
      innerDiv.id = "innerDivID";
      innerDiv.classList.add("innerDivClass");
      innerDiv.innerText = i;
      outsideCaroussel.appendChild(innerDiv);
}
```